# How to get rect of a pygame Surface without transparent parts?

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I am implementing collision detection and want to check if a rectangular object is touching the player. My wall uses `.set_colorkey(background)` where `background` is the specified background colour. The problem is that when I get my wall's rectangle with `.get_rect()`, it gets the full image's size which includes the transparent parts instead of just the opaque parts.

I thought about making the wall image file smaller in size to remove the background but that would be inconvenient as I would need to do this for each partially transparent image I have. I also thought about using arrays to get the colour and checking if it matches the background colour and getting the rectangle's size from there but that would be slow and cumbersome.

```
for x, y in ((i, j) for i in land_x for j in land_y):
# land_x, land_y hold the tiles to be checked
    try:
        tx1, ty1, tx2, ty2 = \
             texture[land[y][x]].get_rect()
        # tx1, ty1 coordinates of top-left corner
        # tx2, ty2 width and height respectively
        if tx2 == 0 and ty2 == 0:
            continue    # skip to other objects
        tx1 = x*64 - tx2/2
        ty1 = y*64 - ty2/2
        px1, py1, px2, py2 = \
             PLAYER.get_rect()
        px1 = player_x - px2/2
        py1 = -player_y - py2/2
        if p.Rect(px1, py1, px2, py2).colliderect(
            p.Rect(tx1, ty1, tx2, ty2)
        ):
            player_x -= direction_x
            break    # go outside loop to start checking y
    except IndexError:    # incase player is outside map
        pass    # skip to other objects
```

The `.get_rect()` outputs a rectangle the size of the whole image whereas I want a rectangle that doesn't include the transparent parts.

Example:
`texture` is a 64x64 image with a 48x48 block in the centre.
The background colour is removed and a 48x48 solid coloured block is left (even though the image size is still 64x64).

Expected Output:
`texture.get_rect()` should output a rectangle of size 48x48.

Actual Output:
`texture.get_rect()` instead outputs a rectangle of size 64x64.

Any help on this would be appreciated :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ignore the transparent pixels in your collision detection, you're talking about pixel-perfect collision.

To do this in pygame, pygame offers the [`Mask`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html) class. You usually create your masks with [`pygame.mask.from_surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.from_surface) and use it together with [`pygame.sprite.spritecollide`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) and [`pygame.sprite.collide_mask`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_mask).

Maybe think about using pygame's [`Sprite`](http://pygame.sprite.Sprite) class to make use of all the features it offers.

Even if you don't want to use pygame's build-in collision detection, you can take a look at the [source](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/blob/96edef0675a7021ca7125be6008846dbf8e3806d/src_py/sprite.py#L1457) to see how it works.

Answer (score 2):

You are making this too hard.  You know the size of your objects. Add a smaller collision rect to each of your objects at creation time and use that for collision.  Or use a circle if that is better for the object.

```
tile.crect = Rect(whatever)
```

Or just multiply the existing rect dimensions by some scale factor for your collision rect. Don't do all of these calculations.  Store a Rect for each collideable object and have a rect for the player.

```
    tx1 = x*64 - tx2/2
    ty1 = y*64 - ty2/2
    px1, py1, px2, py2 = \
         PLAYER.get_rect()
    px1 = player_x - px2/2
    py1 = -player_y - py2/2
```

Then just test collision directly:

```
for t in tiles:
    if player.rect.colliderect( t.rect ):
```

If the player is a sprite its rect moves around. Look at the example code in the doc.

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html

Comment: Thanks for answering with clarity. The game I am making will be able to be changed with different textures with different sizes, thus I won't be able to know the sizes beforehand. I will check out the link on sprites, as that looks useful to me. Thanks again :D

Comment: I've reevaluated my game and how it works. I am going to have users specify the 'hitbox' for a specified texture. Unfortunately, I am going to leave this question unanswered as I want to have a backup for when the user does not specify a 'hitbox'.

Comment: Yeah if the user doesn't specify a hitbox then you would need to check for the transparent pixel and just do that once at the start and create the hitbox Rect or store a ratio like 0.8 and as you are doing multiply the Rect by that before testing collision.